# Set a route for vpn

Tags: networking, vpn

I have a main router ( 192.168.1.1)  which connected Internet Service Provider modem.
My second router ( 192.168.2.1) behind my main router , only for VPN purpose

Since my vpn service using tunneling wire_guard , I add manually route traffic via 192.168.1.1 gateway for assigned vpn IP

eg:

```
ip route add 85.156.24.28/32 via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
```

and works as it should.

Now what become a problem, I am removing the main router ( 192.168.1.1) and use my VPN router ( 192.168.2.1) directly to ISP modem.

so I change the route  to:

```
ip route add 85.156.24.28/32 via 192.168.2.1 dev eth0
```

but my vpn does not work.

also with :

```
ip route add 85.156.24.28/32 dev eth0
```

also my vpn does not work.

I am wondering  work if my modem directly connected  to VPN router.

Please advise

Thank you

Comment: It's unclear where the action is done: on the first router, on a 3rd system, somewhere else? You'd have to describe more precisely your network topology with all the involved addresses (eg: routers usually have two or more etc.) in the state before and in the intended state after.

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved , has to  ISP  IP address instead  router gateway IP ( when router  directly connected  to ISP modem)

eg:
ip route add 85.156.24.28/32 via "ISP IP address " dev eth0